# print the address of a /etc/hosts entry in a script

Tags: linux, bash

Lets say I have an entry called `bob` in the `/etc/hosts` file:

`192.168.1.1 bob`

What I want to do is in a script do somthing like:

`echo "the host bob's address is $bob"`

Such that it prints:

> the host bob's address is 192.168.1.1

The reason is that some scripts we are using require the string address to be passed in and don't handle host names like `bob`. But I can't think how I can print the address of bob to use in this way.

**update**

I was hoping there is a some function (not nessesserily a script) that does this for you? I can write a script to pull the value out. It might be that one does not exist.

Comment: @Cyrus My minimal example is the `echo` line. I don't really see the problem with this question, can you enlighten me further please? : )     Also (maybe not your good self) but -2 seems aweful harsh since its not a dup (AFAIK) its got example code its minimal etc...

Comment: You didn't show what you were trying to do to answer the question yourself. For this there is usually a downvote (usually only from the first who finds the question) and a closevote.

Comment: @Cyrus well... I did I tried `$bob` (obviously not going to work though) and then after some googling I was stumped, so.... I came here with what I had - which looks like not much, but then I just did not detail the googling that I did because that is waffle. Even now I still don't think I can add anything to the question! ...hey ho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use perl:

```sh
perl -we 'printf "%vd\n", scalar(gethostbyname $ARGV[0])' bob
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I was hoping there was a native bash/linux function that did this very much like `gethostbyname`... I am guessing not though?

Comment: @code_fodder https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20784/how-can-i-resolve-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address-in-a-bash-script might be relevant.

Comment: Ah cool, yes there are some nice answers there, I think that is what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` and `awk` for something simple

```
address=$( grep bob /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}' )
echo "the host bob's address is $address"
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I will +1 this, but I was kind of looking for a direct solution (function call or such) instead of a bit of scripting - but I had not specified that before your answer - only after the update  : )